# Overlapping elements Div elements

Tags: html, css

`Div` containaer and `p` element overlapping another `Div` that contains an image that needs to respond to a `:hover` CSS event causing only a small portion of that `Div` container to be able to sense the mouse hovering over it.

- How do I solve this?
- `z-index` isnt effective for some reason either.
- Try and hover your mouse over the image.

**[Here Is The JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7fvcD/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put image as `position: relative`, then `z-index` will work.

Answer (score 4):

As @colandus said adding the `position: relative` and the `z-index` to the `img` should indeed do the trick.

However, it seems to me like you are over complicating things a bit. Why the position relative on the `p`? that is the one that is causing the problem...

What you are trying to do is default behavior if you use some simpler html / css. Something like this:

the **HTML** with some div's removed:

```
<div class="insp">
    <h3>Thomas Edison</h3>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x150">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is s...</p>
</div>
```

and the **css** with the `position: relative` removed from the `p`:

```
.insp {
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    padding:10px;
}
.insp h3 {
    margin-top:0px;
    background-color:#FFDE5C;
}
.insp img {
    float:left;
    border: 5px solid #FFDE5C;
    height:150px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.insp img:hover {
    border: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
.insp p {
    margin: 40px 40px 40px 80px;
}
```

And as you can see (http://jsfiddle.net/7fvcD/4/), it looks exactly the same and there is no hover issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS:

```
.insp-image img {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7fvcD/5/

Don't need to change your markup ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach: Put the `<div>` with the `<img>` inside the `<p>` tag and set some margin to the img div.

[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fvcD/6/)

Comment: I don't think a <div> inside a <p> is a good idea. <p> should only hold elements like <span> or style modifiers, <div> is for structure

Comment: Indeed, but there is not need for a div here so it can be omitted. @PeterVR 's solution is the most clear, but we don't know if divs are needed or not.